# Django filter query using hasattr (or something like it)

Tags: django, filter

I want to perform a filter on a model and return all objects that have a specific attribute.

```
model.objects.filter(hasattr(model, 'attrname'))
```

This obviously doesn't work, but not sure how to efficiently implement something siilar.

Thanks

EDIT

An example of where I would use this is when a model is inherited from another

```
class model1(models.Model):
    ...

class model2(model1):
    ...
```

if I do a `model1.objects.all()` each of the returned objects that are in `model2` will have an extra attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put it in a:

```
try:
    ....
except AttributeError:
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

If the models are related, you can the isnull in the filter.

```
model1.objects.filter('related_name__field_name__isnull=False)
```

where related name is in for the foreign key in model2

For Example:
    class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=10)

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='cars', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For owners with cars:
`owners = Owner.objects.filter(cars__id__isnull=False)`

Comment: Did you mean "use isnull in the filter?"

Comment: @AnnKilzer yes, 'owners = Owner.objects.filter(cars__id__isnull=False)'

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to suppress the FieldError exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(FieldError):
    model.objects.filter(field_in_other_class=value)
```

hope that helps